# sap.m.MessageBox.confirm shows undefined when page refreshed [F5]

Tags: sapui5

Whenever I do page refresh using F5, I get an error:

In debug I see totalRtn has value, so it goes to else - when control goes to sap.m.MessageBox.confirm - I get an error saying "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'confirm' of undefined  "

```
if (totalRtn <= 0) {
                    sap.m.MessageToast.show("Cannot return 0 quantity");
                } else {

                    sap.m.MessageBox.confirm("You are returning total of " + totalRtn + " items from this order", {
                        actions: [sap.m.MessageBox.Action.YES, sap.m.MessageBox.Action.NO],
                        styleClass: "messageBoxError",
                        onClose: function(oAction) {
                            if (oAction === sap.m.MessageBox.Action.YES) {
                                ServiceUtils.createEntry(this, oEntry, sEntity, sURL).done(function(data) {
                                    var jsonModel = new JSONModel(data);
                                    var returnNumber = jsonModel.getProperty("/data/SalesDocument");
                                    sap.m.MessageToast.show("Return " + returnNumber + " is created successfully");
                                    vc.getOwnerComponent().getRouter().navTo("stockrooms", {
                                        "companyId": vc.companyId
                                    }, false);

                                }).fail(function(error) {
                                    sap.m.MessageToast.show("Error in return processing");
                                });
                            } else {
                                sap.m.MessageToast.show("Return not confirmed");
                            }
                        }
                    });
```

Comment: Is the `sap.m` library loaded already at that point in your code? I suggest adding `sap.m.MessageBox` to the `sap.ui.define` part of your controller, and checking the manifest to see which libraries are being preloaded.

Comment: @Jorg It would be nice if you could add the suggestion as an answer so that THI can accept it.

Answer (score 1):

You need load the module **"sap.m.MessageBox"**

Try this:

```
jQuery.sap.require("sap.m.MessageBox");

if (totalRtn <= 0) {
                    sap.m.MessageToast.show("Cannot return 0 quantity");
                } else {

                    sap.m.MessageBox.confirm("You are returning total of " + totalRtn + " items from this order", {
                        actions: [sap.m.MessageBox.Action.YES, sap.m.MessageBox.Action.NO],
                        styleClass: "messageBoxError",
                        onClose: function(oAction) {
                            if (oAction === sap.m.MessageBox.Action.YES) {
                                ServiceUtils.createEntry(this, oEntry, sEntity, sURL).done(function(data) {
                                    var jsonModel = new JSONModel(data);
                                    var returnNumber = jsonModel.getProperty("/data/SalesDocument");
                                    sap.m.MessageToast.show("Return " + returnNumber + " is created successfully");
                                    vc.getOwnerComponent().getRouter().navTo("stockrooms", {
                                        "companyId": vc.companyId
                                    }, false);

                                }).fail(function(error) {
                                    sap.m.MessageToast.show("Error in return processing");
                                });
                            } else {
                                sap.m.MessageToast.show("Return not confirmed");
                            }
                        }
                    });
```

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, MessageBox is a static class, a sap.ui.require("sap/m/MessageBox"); statement must be explicitly executed before the class can be used.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what Jorg mentioned in comment, the most recent best-practices describe that if you are only using a control in some cases, you should only load the library the moment you need it. This will improve the initial loading performance.

In your example you only need to load the `sap.m.MessageBox` library when `totalRtn` is larger than 0. Therefor I'd suggest the following alteration of your provided code:

```
else {
sap.ui.require(["sap/m/MessageBox"], function(oMessageBox) {
    oMessageBox.confirm("You are returning total of " + totalRtn + " items from this order", {
        actions: [sap.m.MessageBox.Action.YES, sap.m.MessageBox.Action.NO],
        styleClass: "messageBoxError",
        onClose: function(oAction) {
            if (oAction === sap.m.MessageBox.Action.YES) {
                ServiceUtils.createEntry(this, oEntry, sEntity, sURL).done(
                    function(data) {
                        var jsonModel = new JSONModel(data);
                        var returnNumber = jsonModel.getProperty("/data/SalesDocument");

                        sap.m.MessageToast.show("Return " + returnNumber + " is created successfully");

                        vc.getOwnerComponent().getRouter()
                        .navTo("stockrooms", 
                            { "companyId": vc.companyId }, 
                            false
                        );
                    }).fail(function(error) {
                            sap.m.MessageToast.show("Error in return processing");
                    });
                } else {
                   sap.m.MessageToast.show("Return not confirmed");
                }
            }
        });
    }.bind(this));
...
```